# Indian English: Is this a correct sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, subcontinental-english

Is this a correct sentence in Indian English?

> It is not very long when my sister will finish their graduation.

Comment: Probably even Indian English would use _her_ instead of _their_ to refer to your sister.

Comment: If what you mean is "Is this Indian English correct in Standard (Atlantic) English?" then, No: you want *until* instead of *when* and, as John Lawler says, *her* instead of *their*.

Comment: I also think of "graduation" as an event not a process.  So keeping your basic sentence structure I'd phrase this as: "It won't be too long until my sister graduates." or turning it around, "My sister will soon be graduating."

Comment: No, never. Your question should not be tagged as Indian English (usage).

Answer (score 2):

Um, no.

> It is not very long **until/till** my sister **finishes** **her** graduation.

or better yet, as Jim said:

> "It won't be too long until my sister graduates"

I don't know why you used `their`. The usage of `sister` identifies the gender and there's no need for the gender-neutral pronoun.

The way you phrased it is wrong, and InE speakers do not phrase it that way.

The only thing woth noting regarding InE here is that the gender-neutrality, when needed, is more likely to be expressed by `his or her` than `their`.

Comment: @MystiSinha :) Took all of my considerable skills of deduction to demystify that one!

Comment: Facebook tends to use 'their' as a neutral pronoun now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good alternative:

> It won't be long before my sister graduates.

---

In any regard, to address the problems in your sentence, you should use "her" instead of "their" because "sister" is explicitly feminine. Also, you want to use a different word in place of "when" such as "until"/"till" or "before".

You also need to clarify your intended meaning. It could be construed as if she is at her graduation ceremony, which is almost done. For instance:

> It won't be long before my sister finishes her graduation.

Or, possibly you mean that she is almost done with her degree, and would say:

> It won't be long before my sister graduates.